# How to make ctrl+enter run the current cell in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

In vscode, I want to run the current cell by "ctrl+enter", but the editor behavior is
"enter"(insert a new line) instead of "run this cell".

"shift+enter" is working, but I don't want to create a new cell.

"ctrl+alt+enter" will pop an error message: *command 'jupyter.runSelectionLine' not found*

Any suggestions to make "ctrl+enter" can run current cell?
I hope it can work like colab.

Comment: related post where I show some inspection of other jupyter/notebook-related `ctrl+enter` keyboard shortcuts: [Why is VS Code's Inspect Context Keys showing "false" for inputFocus when I have focused a notebook cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76940487/11107541)

Answer (score 6):

Didn't work for me too. But it started to work after I installed the "Jupyter Keymap" extension.

This should be helpful https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

`File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

[image]

Search for "execute"

Double click on `Notebook: Execute Cell` and enter your preferred key binding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings enabled (since I moved from PyCharm/IntelliJ). Looks like this extension had conflicts with Jupyter keybindings. I removed it, and it works!
[image]

Maybe you have a conflicting add-on enabled; try disabling it. For me it was IntelliJ IDEA.